# java regex split text with ; but not matching within quotes(including escaped quotes within )

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a string ; as a delimiter. But don't need to parse the text if it is within double quotes.

**Example** I need to parse

```
this ; "but not ; this"
```

For this I have come up with regex pattern which works fine.

```
;(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)
```

Now if text contains escaped quotes, the above pattern doesn't work.

I need to parse

```
this ; "but \" not ; this"
```

Could you help me with the pattern which omits escaped quotes within quotes?

Answer (score 0):

As long as double quotes are not unbalanced you can use this regex with `negative look-behind`:

```
(?s);(?=(?:(?:.*?(?<!\\\\)\"){2})*[^\"]*$)
```

#### Working Demo: http://ideone.com/KmjJXJ

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. It works fine.. But if text contains \n , parsing logic is failing. My previous regex works well with \n \t also.

Comment: Ok in that case you need to use `(?s)` also. See edit.